# Failed to load resource rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I just upgraded to `rxjs 5.4.3` and now I am getting a error in the browser. In my `package.json` I have `"rxjs": "5.4.3"` installed so I am not sure why I am getting this error message?

ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

import { NoteDictionariesServiceModel } from "../../Models/ServiceModels/NoteServiceModels";

@Injectable()
export class NoteEditorContext {

    dictionaries: NoteDictionariesServiceModel;
    onContextInitialized = new Subject();

}
```

Error text:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs
    Error: XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1332:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1744:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1770:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs as "rxjs" from http://localhost:52313/dist/debug/Components/StyleGuideNoteEditor/NoteEditorContext.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: (SystemJS) XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs
    Error: XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1332:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1744:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1770:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs as "rxjs" from http://localhost:52313/dist/debug/Components/StyleGuideNoteEditor/NoteEditorContext.js (SystemJS) XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs
    Error: XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1332:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1744:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:52313/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1770:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:52313/node_modules/rxjs as "rxjs" from http://localhost:52313/dist/debug/Components/StyleGuideNoteEditor/NoteEditorContext.js
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.4.7",
    "a": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-typedoc": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp4-run-sequence": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Comment: @joulukuusi have you seen this error?

Comment: Hi, never seen this but please try importing `Subject` from `rxjs/Rx` or `rxjs/Subject` first. If that doesn't work then we may need to take a look at your SystemJS configuration.

Comment: What version of angular are you using? You may want to check compatibility matrix here https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: I am using angular  4.4.7 from looking at the matrix this should work.

Comment: Based on a suggested solution to [a similar issue](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/11): does importing from `rxjs/Rx` improve anything? Really seems like a version incompatibility, are you able to update to a later version of SystemJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) github page, the version of `rxjs` compatible with your angular version is `5.0.3`.

You should downgrade to that.

I suggest that make your `cli` and `core` versions compatible to each other too.

Check your `node.js` version too.

That page will help you to find which version to upgrade or downgrade to.